# Jenkinsfile add if else script?

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

i would like to integrate a simple if else script to my Jenkinsfile but i have a little problem :

My Bash Script :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e /root/test/*.php ];then
echo "Found file"
else
echo "Did not find file"
fi
```

The Script work very well but if i try to integrate in a stage they dont function :

```
        stage('Test') {
        steps {
            script {
                    if [ -e "/root/test/*.php" ];then
                        echo found
                    else 
                        echo not found
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You have lots of extra curly brackets there. Could they be the cause?

Comment: `script { … }` wants a *Groovy* script, not a shell script. You could rewrite it in Groovy, or run a shell script with `sh '…'`.

Comment: I change a little bit the Jenkinsfile but same error. They say that something not correct with [ -e

Comment: @Biffen How i can integrate an shell script instead groovy ? Or did you know a simple script to search in a folder .php files ?

Comment: @M.Antony Ask your favourite search engine about how to find files in Groovy. Or, as I mentioned, use `sh '…'` (you can use other types of quotes, e.g. `'''…'''` if you want to write it on multiple lines).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pipeline's `script` step expects Groovy script, not Bash script - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script

Instead of using `script` step you can use [`sh` step which is designed to execute shell scripts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script). Something like this (this is just an example):

```groovy
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''#!/bin/bash
            if [ -e /root/test/*.php ];then
            echo "Found file"
            else
            echo "Did not find file"
            fi
        '''.stripIndent())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works :) One more question what exactly .stripIndent and returnStdout make ?

Comment: `returnStdout` is optional parameter and is used if you want to capture the output of a command. `stripIndent()` is a Groovy method to remove indention in a given string (without it all lines starting from the 2nd one would have this indention of a several whitespaces).